# Jquery animate and fade in on hover of containing div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate the 'title' so it fades in as well as animates up 10px as you hover the containing div. Would this require javascript or can it be done with CSS transitions?

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aGcpR/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumb">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="copy">
             <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.content').hide().removeClass('content').addClass('content-js');

$('.thumb').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.content-js').fadeToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aGcpR/15/ which is this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.thumb').hover(
     function () {
        $('.copy h1').fadeIn(0).animate({'font-size':'20px'});
     },
     function () {
        $('.copy h1').animate({'font-size':'1px'}).fadeOut(0);
    });
});
```

I've animated title to 20px so you can see it better, but you can see where it says 20px. .hover() takes 2 functions as arguments (ie separated by a comma). The first function is when you mouseenter, the second is when you mouseleave. See this documentation: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Note, I set the font-size for that element to 1px and hid it to start with:

```
.copy h1 {
    font-size: 1px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: how would you recommend for it to return when you rolloff? ie: returns back to 1px

Comment: Only just seen your comment. Let me update it to roll on roll off.

Comment: @Rob answer now updated with both mouseeneter and mouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple css3 transitions (comma-delimited).  In your case, I'd use opacity and either height or font-size.